# HTML Embeddings into Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, word-embedding

I'm beginning my journey into Neural Networks and trying to understand both character and word embeddings as ways to input text data into a NN.  Specifically, I am trying to embed HTML tag information.  I tried googling some different combinations of my problem and came up empty.

My current understanding is that embeddings "embed" words or characters into an N-Dimensional space, which allows NNs to be able to understand them as inputs.  So in this case, something like word2vec would not necessarily help me because it is not meant to understand the "meaning" of HTML elements?  So thus a character embedding would be better?

If anyone could point me in a direction that would be awesome, as I am having trouble finding this on my own.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you going to do with result embeddings? Do you want to just feed html tags as input to NN?

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding! I am using the result embeddings to input as part of a feature vector to a NN classifier along with pre-trained word2vec word embeddings of the content.  I did more research and figured out that this does indeed work, and am currently implementing!